# How to add dbus to an embedded python package

Tags: python, linux, centos, rpm, dbus

I'm creating an omnibus rpm package with embedded python and need to include dbus in my build.

So I tried to install dbus-python and got this error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (dbus-1 >= 1.6) were not met:

No package 'dbus-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DBUS_CFLAGS
and DBUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the C-level D-Bus development package, `dbus-devel`.

Comment: On Ubuntu I had to do: `sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev`